# OData IEnumerable or IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, query-optimization, odata-v4

I'm still pretty new to OData v3/v4 and use the OData Connect Service in Visual Studio to get data from OData servers. Now my question is what would be the best, and fastest approach to GET data en then validate it with own collection?

For example we have a `Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery` of Type `Employee` we want to GET all employees from the server and compare it with our local dataset for example from another CRM system as `List(Of Employee)`

To GET data from the OData service we have to setup the `DataServiceQuery` for example: a simple one to GET all Employees is `DataServiceQuery.GetAllPages`this returns an `IEnumerable(Of Employee)` on which we can call the `.ToList` function. After this we can do every comparison and update collection between the two Lists using LINQ and/or LAMBDA.

But now if i change the approach by using `DataServiceQuery.Take(Number)` then it returns an `IQueryable(Of Employee)` on which we can also call the `.ToList` Or is that unnecessary with an `IQueryable`?

So my question here is what would be the best approach to GET all data from the OData v4 server and then stuff it in memory and then use LINQ and/or LAMBDA to compare stuff?

Comment: Using `ToList` is inefficient if you need only iterate data just once (to compare with other list it's enough), because you have to allocate buffer for all the data in addition to buffers that your data service uses. If you are restricted and cannot alter method that compares your lists and change one list to `IEnumerable<T>` or don't care about memory and performance, just use `ToList` on both.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your solutions in effect will do the *same thing*, the only difference is that by using the `.Take()` you are composing a query in this case that will batch the data from the server, you might be more familiar with this being referred to as *Paging*.

In the OData server logic, the difference between IEnumerable an IQueryable is significant, as an IQueryable is deferred *until* you iterate the query, calls like `.ToList()` will force this iteration.

On the client side however, even though the data type is a *Linq* `IQueryable` type, when you have finished composing the query you can only iterate it once, this is also true of the `IEnumerable` responses from `DataServiceQuery`.

> But now if i change the approach by using DataServiceQuery.Take(Number) then it returns an IQueryable(Of Employee) on which we can also call the .ToList Or is that unnecessary with an IQueryable?

Specifically for `DataServiceQuery`, given that we can only iterate the response once, as a general pattern, we usually *DO* call `.Tolist()` to forcibly receive the response from the server, and so it is obvious that it was our intent to do so.

- It's not a question of being necessary or not, it is the deliberate intent to download the data once, and store it in a list variable that allows us to iterate over it again.

The `IQueryable` response allows you to build the filter, order and projection expression before sending that to the server, in OData terms this should translate to `$filter`, `$orderby`, `$expand`, `$select`, `$skip` and `$top` query options to be sent with the HTTP request. If you were going to apply any of those it would have improve performance but that doesn't look to apply here.

So in regard to your question, because you are GETTING **ALL** of the data, there is no performance difference between these two types of responses from `DataServiceQuery`. When you don't want **ALL** rows, then one fact comes into play:

> If you have limited the number of records using `Where()` or `ApplyQueryOption()` or `.Take()` then because the payload will be smaller than a non-limited query it will return faster, purely by virtue of the data payload over the wire being smaller.

If you were to call `.ToList()` and *then* apply filtering or limiting, the entire collection would have to be downloaded first, before your filter could be evaluated, so you get the best performance by using the `IQueryable` and applying filter criteria *before* you execute it.

Again, for your specific task, as it involves iterating over the entire collection neither of these has any inherent benefit over the other. If the record set is large though, I would encourage you to use batching/paging to process the records in smaller sets so as not to lock up the server resources, and to *NOT* run out of memory trying to deserialize the entire result set in a single operation.

---

These types of data synchronisations are generally expensive processes to run either way, however by performing this operation on a client you have probably picked the least efficient mechanism.

If you can, this task should be performed on the server side, that way you can reduce one whole round trip of data comparisons

---

If the comparisons cannot be performed on the server, then perhaps you can formulate you comparison into the `IQueryable` expression and only return the matches, or the non-matching results, that is where the power of the `IQueryable` comes to play, it will pass the expression to the server to perform the comparison in the database directly.